# ng-show not working in angular project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-show

I am trying to hide a button if a condition is satisfied. This should be very easy by using `ng-show` but for some reason I am having difficulties in implementing this.

My code is as follows:

**html**

```
<a href = "example.com" ng-click="Bookings.disableCancelFirstBooking(car)">
     <i class="red" ng-show="Bookings.disableCancellationButton">
     </i>
</a>
```

controller.js

```
this.disableCancellationButton = true;

this.disableCancelFirstBooking = function(carID){

 BookingsResource.firstBookingOfSubscription({id: carID},  $.proxy(function () {
       if(carID.status === 'waiting'){                    
            this.disableCancellationButton = false;
            console.log(this.disableCancellationButton)
            console.log('why does this not work?')
        }
    }));
}
```

and finally the service that I am implementing

```
  firstBookingOfSubscription: {
                    method: "GET",
                    url: 'example/bookings/:id/cars',
                    isArray: true
                }
```

The strange thing is that I am seeing the message `'why does this not work?'` in the console along with the `this.disableCancellationButton = false;`

any ideas why the icon is then not been hidden?

I have read through many SO posts but cannot find a relevant answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the callback `this` has changed scope (one of the advantages of ES6 `=>` is that the`this` is handled for you there). Try this (no pun intended):

```
var self = this
this.disableCancellationButton = true;

this.disableCancelFirstBooking = function(carID){

 BookingsResource.firstBookingOfSubscription({id: carID},  $.proxy(function () {
       if(carID.status === 'waiting'){                    
            self.disableCancellationButton = false;
            //^^
            console.log(this.disableCancellationButton)
            console.log('why does this not work?')
        }
    }));
}
```

Comment: absolutely brilliant Simon, thank you. I was unaware of that. Will give you a green tick when I can

Comment: why not using $scope object  ?

Comment: @sick see my answer to JonathanTheBrosh

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use $scope to your disableCancellationButton variable. I think your variable is update but not transmis to the view.

Comment: The questioner is using `ControllerAs` which is considered the way forward for Angular

Comment: Thanks, I don't knew the controllerAs.